# Entity Framework Core Cosmos Db - How to compare strings, case insensitive?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I tried a few variants:

```cs
entity.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => string.Equals(x.Id, Id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
entity.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(Id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Also tried `ToUpper()` method:

```cs
var IdUpper = Id.ToUpper();
entity.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.ToUpper() == idUpper);
```

But all solution throw error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression could not be translated

Is there a solution that would support EF Core for Cosmos Db?

Comment: Strings are compared by the *database* based on the field's collation - that specifies the sort order, character equality rules etc. What you tried would fail with SQL Server as well. Since the collation specifies the sort order, it affects how indexes are built too, so you *shouldn't* try to override the field's collation. You'd end up with a full table scan, as the server would have to check every single value to see if it matches using the new collation

Comment: [Case-insensitive StringEquals was added to CosmosDB just this June](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/new-string-function-performance-improvements-and-case-insensitive-search/#stringequals). Which EF Core/CosmosDB provider version are you using? Older providers won't support this functionality.

Comment: Glad to hear it - I couldn't find any release notes or relevant Github issues

Comment: Now I checked that Equals works fine but doesn't work with the Type comparison parameter (StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) I get this same error.

Comment: After checking the provider dependencies it looks like the first CosmosDB provider version with a dependency on the SDK that introduced case-insensitivity is 5.0 RC1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Case-insensitive StringEquals was added to CosmosDB just this June](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/new-string-function-performance-improvements-and-case-insensitive-search/#stringequals). You should update your EF Core Cosmos provider to [the latest version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos/).  Versions released before June 2020 won't have this feature.

I can't find any release notes or GitHub issues that specify which version first introduced case-invariant comparisons, so I can't say which version introduced this feature. Package dependencies show that v 5.0 RC1 is the first to take an explicit dependency on a CosmosDB SDK with that feature.

In case of problems it's probably better to use the [Cosmos .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-dotnet) directly.

As for why this is an issue at all, string comparisons are performed on the *server*, based on a field's collation. The collation specifies the sort order to use and which characters are considered equal. `AA` in Danish is considered a single letter that comes after Z for example. Database indexes are built using that collation, so trying to search for values using a *different* collation won't be able to use any existing indexes. The server is forced to scan all the data and calculate equality and ordering. Using functions like `ToLower()` is just as expensive.